# Number of rows updated in a oracle table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I  have a table called t1 which is already updated by a file. I have table t2 which is created as backup for table t1 before modifications. Now I want to know how many records got updated in table t1. Is there anyway that I can do join with back up table and know how many records got altered? Or how to use `sql%rowcount` function on a already updated table? Or how should i proceed with `ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables on their primary key (cos you didn't update that, hopefully!) and then compare every column.. you'll have to check for nulls too, and it'll make quite a lot of typing. You could use all_tab_cols and a bit of sql to create your query though (write an sql that creates sql as its output )

Actually, thinking about it, you might be able to get away with less typing by doing a natural join the tables together to get a set of rows that didn't change and removing that set from the original full set:

```
select * from original
Minus
select original.* from original natural inner join backup
```

Ive never done it, but the theory is that natural join joins on all equal column names so every column of each table will feature in the join condition. It's an inner join so only columns that have not changed will be represented. Any columns that have become null or become valued from null will also disappear. This is hence the set of rows that have not changed. If all you're after is a count, do a count of the original table less the count of this join result. If you want to know which rows changed, do the result set minus.

Ideally you shouldn't do this; instead at the point the update is run, capture the number of rows it affected. However, this technique could be used long after the update was performed (but before some other update was run)